# javascript replace property name in n-ary tree object

Tags: javascript

Supose I have a n-ary tree structure (in json) like this:

```json
[
  {
    "text": "Some title",
    "children": [
      {
        "text": "Some title",
        "children": [
          ...
        ]
      },
      ...  
    ]
  }
]
```

Where I neither know how many children the nodes will have nor the tree's depth.

What I would like to do is change the name of property `text` to `name`, across all children.

I've tryed this, with a recursive function `func`:

```js
func(tree) {
  if (!tree) return;

  for (let node of tree) {
    node.name = node.text
    delete node.text;
    
    return func(node.children);
  }
}
```

But it didn't work. How would I do that?

Comment: That's not json. JSON is a text format. What you have there is a JavaScript object literal.

Comment: um, what is the actual function? seems like you missing part of it.

Comment: sorry, just updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say, the main problem with your code is that `node` variable holds *the value* of corresponding array items and it doesn't keep the reference to those items themselves, so, basically, mutations you attempt to make are never applied to original array (but only to temporary variable reassigned upon each loop iteration)

If you prefer to mutate original array and feel comfortable using `for(`-loops for that purpose, you'd be much better off using `for(..in`-loop to access array items by their keys:

```js
const src = [
  {
    text: "Some title",
    children: [
      {
        text: "Some title",
        children: []
      },
    ]
  }
],

    func = tree => {
      for(const nodeIdx in tree){
        const {text:name, children} = tree[nodeIdx]
        func(children)
        tree[nodeIdx] = {name, children}
      }
    }
    
func(src)

console.log(src)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

However, I would avoid mutating source data and return new array instead (e.g. with `Array.prototype.map()`:

```js
const src = [
  {
    text: "Some title",
    children: [
      {
        text: "Some title",
        children: []
      },
    ]
  }
],

      func = tree => 
        tree.map(({text:name,children}) => ({
          name, 
          ...(children && {children: func(children)})
        }))


console.log(func(src))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would use the in operator here.

```
for (let node **in** tree) {
  node.name = node.text
  delete node.text;

    
  return func(node.children);
}
```